# FindOneAndUpdate overriding and updating only the first id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, findoneandupdate

I am simply trying to update the content according to the id, but whichever id I am using, it updates only the first id by overriding it.
The flow goes as routes => controller => repository
Following is the code:
Routes =>

```
router.post("/:pageId/content", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const pageId = req.params;
    const pageContent = req.body;
    if (!pageId || !pageContent) {
      throw {
        statusCode: 200,
        customMessage: "All parameters are required"
      };
    }
    const result: any = await webpageController.createContent(
      pageId,
      pageContent
    );
    if (result.isError) {
      throw result.error;
    }
    res.status(200).json(result.data);
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
});
```

Controller =>

```
const createContent = async (pageId: any, pageContent: any) => {
  try {
    // calls repository to create content
    const result = await webpageRepository.createContent(pageId, pageContent);
    // if result is not success, throw error
    if (!result.success) {
      throw {
        statusCode: 400,
        customMessage: "Unable to create web page content"
      };
    }

    return {
      isError: false,
      data: result.data
    };
```

Repository =>

```
export const createContent = async (pageId: any, content: any) => {
  try {
    const result = await webpage.findOneAndUpdate(pageId, { content });
    return {
      data: result,
      success: true
    };
  } catch (error) {
    logger.error(
      `at:"repositories/webpage/createContent" => ${JSON.stringify(error)}`
    );
    return {
      success: false
    };
  }
};
```

Here it can be seen that the id I have used in the route and the id getting updated is different.
What am I doing wrong here?
[image]

Following is the schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const webpage = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
      maxlength: 25,
    },
    slug: {
      type: String,
    //   required: true,
    },
    url: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true
    },
    content: Object,
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  },
);

export default mongoose.model('webpages', webpage);
```

Comment: I get error when I use this, I have tried this earlier also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use a dictionary as the parameter.

```
const result = await webpage.findOneAndUpdate({_id:pageId.pageId}, {content});
```

You can check on this documentation about how to use the "findOneAndUpdate" https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html#getting-started

Comment: I have tried using what you suggested @taipei but I get error

Comment: Could you tell me what's the error?

Comment: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ pageId: '6204ffcc494d63c93aed1f3f' }" (type Object) at path "_id" for model 
"webpages"    - @taipei

Comment: Can you edit your question by adding your webpage schema?

Comment: sounds like `pageId === {pageId: '6204ffcc494d63c93aed1f3f' }` can you log what `pageId` is? You might have to use `pageId.pageId`

Comment: I agree with you @knicholas, it seems her pageId is a dictionary, if it's true, so Ritika needs to change it, findOneAndUpdate({_id:pageId.pageId }

Comment: @taipei the solution worked!

Comment: @Ritika glad that it helps you, could you flag my answer as a correct answer if that solves your problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
const result = await webpage.findOneAndUpdate(   {_id:pageId.pageId} , { content });
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.